# Send packet from a network adapter to another network adapter on the same computer

Tags: java, sockets, udp, packet

Basically what I want to do is simulate an application with 4 clients and 1 server, but I only have one computer to do so.

I created two loopback adapter 169.254.153.173 (server) and 169.254.168.136 (client) to test.

```
public class Server {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(9001, InetAddress.getByName("169.254.153.173"));
      System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());
      System.out.println();

      byte[] buf = new byte[1];
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

      socket.receive(packet);
      System.out.println(packet.getAddress());
      System.out.println(packet.getPort());
      System.out.println(buf[0]);
      System.out.println();

      socket.close();
   }
}

public class Client {
   public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
      DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(9000, InetAddress.getByName("169.254.168.136"));
      System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress());

      byte[] buf = {42};
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, InetAddress.getByName("169.254.153.173"), 9001);
      socket.send(packet);

      socket.close();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, even tho the code looks fine, my server never receives the packet. I know it works using localhost but that's not what I want since I want to bind the ip to the socket as if it was on another computer.

Comment: have you tried getByAddress insteadof getByName?

Comment: I ended up using a virtual machine! Couldn't get it working even with getByAddress.